# Redirection From Action Play Framework

Tags: redirect, playframework

How do I redirect to another route if certain condition does not fulfill in Action. Below is the code.

```
public class MAction extends Action<M> {

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(final Context ctx) {
        Request request = ctx.request();
        String deviceID   = request.getHeader("deviceID");
        if (deviceID == null || deviceID.isEmpty()) {
            // RETURN TO A DIFFERENT ROUTE from here
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
    CompletionStage<Result> promiseOfResult = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<Result>() {

    @Override
    public Result get() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return redirect(routes.Top.index());
    }
});

    return promiseOfResult;
```